# When running a Django dev server with docker/fig, why is some of the log output hidden?

Tags: django, shell, exec, docker, fig

I'm writing a Dockerfile which needs to run multiple commands as part of the `CMD` instruction and I thought the right way to do this would be to run a shell script with the main daemon executed via `exec`. Unfortunately, as part of that process some of my output (stdout? stderr? I don't know, and I don't know how to find out) gets lost.

Here's the shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py migrate
exec python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The idea being that the `migrate` command is just run once and its output shown, and then the `runserver` command should take over and the container runs until that process exits.

The actual problem is that the output of `migrate` is displayed correctly, but the immediate output of `runserver` is not shown. Strangely, later request logging of `runserver` is shown just fine.

To clarify, here's the output I expected:

```
[...]
No migrations to apply.
[...]
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[21/Jan/2015 16:27:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 15829
```

Here's what I'm getting with `fig up`:

```
[...]
No migrations to apply.
[...]
[21/Jan/2015 16:27:06] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 15829
```

I'm not even sure who's fault this is. Does the `runserver` command change its output depending on how it is run? Is it a problem with `exec`? Is it docker/fig?

As one additional data point, I noticed that I do get all the output when running the container with `fig run web`, but not when I do `fig up`, but I don't understand how that's different or relevant.

Note: sorry for the tag spam, I'll reduce the tags once I know what actually causes this effect.

Comment: You could redirect output manually, and use append redirects `>>` later.

Comment: @Paul What do you mean? I'm not using any `>>` append redirects.

Comment: Why running migrate before each runserver? You can make`django-admin.py` an entrypoint and run migration like `fig run <service> migrate`.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz This is a dev environment setup aimed at non-technical people. The source code will be hooked in via a host-shared volume. I can't expect them to type `fig run <service> migrate` everytime the migrations change (assume they don't know what migrations are or when a new migration has been committed, nor do they care). The setup just has to always work on `fig up`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found this old issue today using docker composer. Python logging module checks the output is a terminal so you need to add `tty: true` to the service. Example:

```
version: '2'
services:
  django:
    tty: true
    command: python -u manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: Don't have the ability to test this right now, but sounds like a very plausible explanation, so thanks for posting your findings here!

Comment: Works perfectly for me, thanks very much. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: Accepted, based on Robin's confirmation.