# manage.py doesn't log to stdout/stderr in Docker on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

On a Raspberry Pi 2, I used the image `resin/rpi-raspbian:stretch` for running a Django application. In my Dockerfile, I Install the `python3` package and start the application using `ENTRYPOINT python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000`. This works, BUT when my code throws error, I got NO output using `docker log` command.

#### Example

I have a ImportError. When I run the command manually using `docker exec`, I got the exception as expected:

```
pi@pi2:/etc/docker/container/pms $ sudo docker exec -it pms_app_1 python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x75de3228>
[...]
ImportError: No module named 'ws4redisfrontend'
```

But when I run the container using `docker-compose` and then open the logs, they're empty:

```
pi@pi2:/myapp $ sudo docker logs myapp_1
pi@pi2:/myapp $
```

This behaviour is only present for the `manage.py` call. For example, when I extend the entrypoint like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT python3 -c "print('printed by python inline script')" && python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

I see *printed by python inline script* in the container-logs. As a newbie in Python/Django, I can't understand why this happens. But as my print example works, it seems a Django issue, and no general problem of Python. What am I missing? Debug mode is activated in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 12):

[`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/) shows by default the I/O streams *STDOUT* and *STDERR*. Check if
[Django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) in your `settings.py` is properly configured.

For example:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {  # 'catch all' loggers by referencing it with the empty string
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438642/django-setup-default-logging)

Also worth to mention:

> **Changed in Django 1.10:**
>
> In older versions, log messages were written
> to sys.stderr instead of being handled through Python logging.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#runserver

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the same problem I was struggling with, but in my situation I couldn't see any errors informations from Django in my docker console using docker-compose. If for example I had a typo in any of my imports it wouldn't show me anything, my container just wouldn't get up.

What helped me was an answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072259/when-running-a-django-dev-server-with-docker-fig-why-is-some-of-the-log-output) and after adding 'tty: true' in my docker-compose file it got fixed. Now I can see all errors as well as regular prints.

Hope it's gonna help someone.